# what is 400 bad request and how to solve this

Tags: esp8266, iot

```
AT+CIPSEND=65
link is not valid

ERROR

OK

OK

OK

OK
STATUS:2

OK
\x0BQ\xADUART_DEF=115200,8,1,0,0ATE0
AT+CWMODE=3
AT+CIPMUX=0
AT+CIPMODE=0
AT+CIPSTATUS
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","api.thingspeak.com",80
AT+CIPSTATUS
CONNECT

OK
STATUS:3
+CIPSTATUS:0,"TCP","52.0.107.28",80,38071,0

OK

OK
> AT+CIPSEND=65
GET api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=M
Recv 65 bytes
E5K4JWXT2ZBSBZ8&field1=0

SEND OK

+IPD,272:HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Tue, 23 May 2023 05:45:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 122
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
CLOSED
```

Comment: your HTTP request does not match the HTTP protocol

Answer (score 1):

The server name does not belong to the `GET` request line: it has to be
provided in the `Host` request header.

Try something this:

```cpp
server.println("GET /update?api_key=ME5K4JWXT2ZBSBZ8&field1=0 HTTP/1.0");
server.println("Host: api.thingspeak.com");
server.println();  // empty line means "end of request headers"
```